# Can I shorten this filter, that finds disk sizes over 100G?

Tags: awk, grep, disk, lsblk

My goal is to get the disks greater than 100G from lsblk.

I have it working, but it's awkward. I'm pretty sure it can be shortened. Either by using something totally different than lsblk, or maybe I can filter human readable numbers directly with awk.

Here's what I put together:

```
lsblk | grep disk | awk '{print$1,$4}' | grep G | sed 's/.$//' | awk '{if($2>100)print$1}'
```

It outputs only the sdx and nvmexxx part of the disks larger than 100G. Exactly what I need.

I am happy with it, but am eager to learn more from you Gurus

Comment: between 100-999GB and larger than 100T, but nothing between 1-99T, i presume? (terabytes~)

Comment: Yes that is one flaw that slipped my attention and was already discussed in the answers. I therefore accepted the answer to do the filter based on byte size instead of human readable. If you of another method I'll be happy to learn about that to.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can specify the form of output you want from `lsblk`:

```
% lsblk -nblo NAME,SIZE
mmcblk0   15931539456
mmcblk0p1   268435456
mmcblk0p2 15662038528
```

[Options used](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/lsblk.8.html):

```
-b, --bytes
      Print the SIZE column in bytes rather than in human-readable format.

-l, --list
      Use the list output format.

-n, --noheadings
      Do not print a header line.

-o, --output list
      Specify which output columns to print.  Use --help to get a list of  all  supported
      columns.
```

Then the filtering is easier:

```
% lsblk -nblo NAME,SIZE | awk '$2 > 4*2^30 {print $1}' # greater than 4 GiB
mmcblk0
mmcblk0p2
```

In your case, that'd be `100*2^30` for 100GiB or `100e9`/`1e11` for 100GB.

Comment: Uhhh, that's clever! Weeding out what's not needed in the first place. One question: You're using x*2\*\*30 just for consistency with the bytes? Would there be drawback to use s.th. like 10\*\*3?

Comment: @chalybeum yes, for bytes. No, you can use 10**9. The values don't differ all much.

Comment: Note that OP is filtering out partitions in the one-liner.

Comment: @UncleCarl [noted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533331/can-i-shorten-this-filter-that-finds-disk-sizes-over-100g/533337?noredirect=1#comment987257_533334)

Comment: I'm going with this. It fits my brain the best out the given answers.

Comment: Note that in this particular case of 100G boundary awk could also be shortened to `egrep '\d{12,}'` to remove lines with <12 digits in a sequence. Awk is of course more universal.

Comment: Oh, another nice to know thing. During discussion and research of this problem I am considering switching to Perl since it would remove the need to use multiple tools together.

Answer (score 18):

You can also tell `lsblk` to output in JSON format and do the filtering with `jq`:

```
$ lsblk -Jb | jq -r '..|select(.size? >= 1e11).name'
sda
sda2
```

Or:

```
$ lsblk -Jb | jq -r '..|select(.type? == "disk" and .size? >= 1e11).name'
sda
```

To limit to entries of type `disk`.

(`1e11` being 100 GB. Replace with `107374182400` (or `100*1024*1024*1024`) for 100 GiB. Because of rounding, `lsblk` itself without `-b` reports 100G for sizes ranging from about 99.9278 to 100.0488 GiB (for some reason))

With `lsblk -OJb`, `lsblk` reports all available information which lets you do a more fined-grained selection or output more or more relevant information.

You could also get the information directly from `/sys`. With `zsh`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' /sys/class/block/*(e'[(($(<$REPLY/size) * 512 >= 1e11))]':t)
sda
sda2
```

Comment: This is a true answer from a Guru, no one will be able to read it. :D

Comment: I take this as a nice to know. But at this stage of my journey in bash I don't want to introduce further complexity by using yet another tool.

Comment: That's a nice application of `jq` (which I learned about only some months ago).

Answer (score 6):

try

```
lsblk| awk '$4 ~ /G$/ && $4+0 > 100 {print $1}'
```

this will grep and filter at same time.

- `$4 ~ /G$/` get filed with size in G
- `$4+0 > 100` get size over 100G
- `{print $1}` print NAME

as a rule you should never need to use `grep` and `awk` in same pipe.

to get only disk (and no partition) : *awk filtering*

```
lsblk| awk '$4 ~ /G$/ && $4+0 > 100 && $6 == "disk"  {print $1}'
```

where

- `$6 == "disk"` select only column with disk

to get only disk (and no partition) : *lsblk filtering*

```
lsblk --nodeps| awk '$4 ~ /G$/ && $4+0 > 100 {print $1}'
```

where

- `--nodeps` : -d, --nodeps         don't print slaves or holders

Comment: Almost there. It still prints partitions. But I think I can get behind that when I have a bit free time.

Comment: @chalybeum I fixed that, same filtering trick can be applied to muru's answer.

Comment: (Though I'd probably use the `--no-deps` option, in keeping with the general style of that answer)

Comment: I'm afraid this will fail to catch disks whose size is shown in terabytes (or bigger units).

Comment: @fra-san fair point and is also true for my original solution. So I'm taking the disk filter bit from here and put it in the byte conversion.